# Trying to use a String.Format in a Repeater but a getting syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater, string.format

I don't get what I am doing wrong with this code. I think it might have to do with the (`"` or `'`)s

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassportNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="19"
    Text="<%#  String.Format('{0}{1}','######',((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber.Text.Remove(0,6)) %>"
    Enabled="<%# IsOutsideTenDayCutoff %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

**I get too many character error**

Switched to:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassportNumber" runat="server"
     Text="<%#  String.Format("{0}{1}","######",((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber.Text.Remove(0,6)) %>"
     Enabled="<%# IsOutsideTenDayCutoff %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

And get this error:

**Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.**

Final Code that worked thanks to good help:

```
Text='<%# (((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber != null &&  ((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber != "") ? "******" + ((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber.ToString().Remove(0,6) : "" %>'
```

Comment: If this is something you use often, you may want to make a new property of `TSAPassenger` that you can call to get a "masked" passport number, instead of formatting it everywhere you use it.

Comment: You haven't paid enough attention and you are still using `"` to enclose the `Text` attribute value. Switch to `'` for enclosing (just after the `... Text=` and before `Enabled=...`) as me, Abe Miessler and Kelsey suggested. Keep the `"` *inside* the attribute's script syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you use single quote for the `Text` property eg `Text='yourstuff'`.

Then use double quotes inside your bind statement.  The code in the bind must be vanilla c#, if it won't compile in a .cs file it won't compile inline either and single quotes mean a char in c#, not a string.

This works:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassportNumber" runat="server"
    Text='<%# string.Format("{0}{1}", "######", ((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber.Text.Remove(0,6)) %>'
    Enabled="<%# IsOutsideTenDayCutoff %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

Notice the single and double quotes.  You should be able to copy and paste it as is.

Comment: This is the error i get for this one:
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1566783 so your problem is fixed with the formatting it sounds like and you are not using the object you are trying to bind correctly. `((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber` does not have a property called `Text`. You should be able to step through this issue as it is not related to the `string.Format` problem.  This is why I prefer to use the `OnDataBinding` event of each control instead of doing inline data binding.  Much cleaner code wise and easier to debug.

Comment: Ok I understand now where is it my object and I am unsure if this is a string or int so will figure that out and get this set. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is what got my final result
Text='<%# (((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber != null &&  ((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber != "") ? "******" + ((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber.ToString().Remove(0,6) : "" %>'

Comment: @user1566783 when code starts getting that complicated, moving it out of the markup will make things a lot easier to deal with for the next guy :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use double quotation mark instead single

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassportNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="19" Text="<%#  String.Format("{0}{1}","######",((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber.Text.Remove(0,6)) %>" Enabled="<%# IsOutsideTenDayCutoff %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: get the error The server tag is not well formed. and i even removed the maxlength because with the ticks i was getting too many characters error

Comment: This is not helpful at all. It's actually not working and even more confusing as it is still generating syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should invert the usage of `'` and `"` in the `Text` attribute. Instead of:

```
Text="<%#  String.Format('{0}{1}','######',((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber.Text.Remove(0,6)) %>"
```

use:

```
Text='<%#  String.Format("{0}{1}","######",((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber.Text.Remove(0,6)) %>'
```

You have to provide a valid `C#` syntax between the `<%# ... %>` tags. `'"{0}{1}"'` and `'######'` are both invalid in `C#` syntax, as `''` can only enclose `char`s  (`'a'`,`'0'` and so on).

Comment: I then get this error though with the "s
The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a string using `'`.  What you are doing now is trying to create a multiple character char which is not doable.

Try changing it to this:

```
Text='<%#  String.Format("{0}{1}","######",((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber.Text.Remove(0,6)) %>'
```

Comment: Two things - Try making the TextBox tag self closing (remove the `</asp:TextBox>` tag).  Also make sure you are using single quotes around everything after `Text=`